# Is there a New Latin word for Cyborg?

Tags: new-latin, modern-life, neologism

Good day!

Originally “cyborg” came from English *cybernetic organism*. In Latin that would of course be *organismus cyberneticus*. Given the mouthful of that, it is no wonder that people tend to simply use the undeclinable “cyborg” instead. But is there any reputed word used for “cyborg” in Latin that is shorter than that? The same way “robot” has *robotum* and “car” has *autocinetum*.

Thanks in advance for the answer!

EDIT: Just to make clear what a cyborg is (which would probably help the answers). A cyborg is a being that is partially organic and partially machine. This is different from an android that is just a machine that mimics the human form.

Comment: What about some translation using "Animatus-a-um" meaning "endowed with spirit."

Comment: @Nickimite *Anima cybernetica*, maybe? And just *cybernetica* (sc. anima) in latter occurences?

Comment: @Figulus That intuitively sounds like "cybernetic soul" to me. It might work, but I think "animata cybernetica would be better." Using the participle feels more like "animated cybernetic (person)"

Comment: @Nickimite Yes, "cybernetic soul" is sort of what I was going for. I think *animātus* works too in the right context, but in the wrong context, it might sound like you were bringing something non-living to life, animating a machine, rather than mechanizing an organism. So I suggested *anima cybernētica*, although *homo cybernēticus* might be  a better choice, depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like *anima* more than *organismus*, so I guess I'd prefer *anima cybernētica* to *cybernēticus organismus*, or just *cybernētica* for short. Of course, *cybernēticus [homo]* or *cybernēticum [animal]* would also work.